# PM2 with NodeJs crashing then restart every 1 second

Tags: node.js, vps, pm2

I have a NodeJs+Express+Mongodb app and I'm trying to run it on my vps. There was a crashing problem with mongo so I removed "mongo.conf" file. Usually my app start crashing after few minutes. But after this change, everything was good for 24h then my server crash and restart every 1 second :

pm2.log (loop)

```
2021-04-25T09:46:58: PM2 log: App [server:1] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-25T09:46:58: PM2 log: App [server:1] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-25T09:46:58: PM2 log: App [server:1] online
2021-04-25T09:47:00: PM2 log: App [server:1] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-25T09:47:00: PM2 log: App [server:1] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-25T09:47:00: PM2 log: App [server:1] online
2021-04-25T09:47:02: PM2 log: App [server:1] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-25T09:47:02: PM2 log: App [server:1] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-25T09:47:02: PM2 log: App [server:1] online
2021-04-25T09:47:34: PM2 log: App [server:1] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2021-04-25T09:47:34: PM2 log: App [server:1] starting in -fork mode-
2021-04-25T09:47:34: PM2 log: App [server:1] online
```

server-error.log (loop)

```
Deprecation warning: use moment.updateLocale(localeName, config) to change an existing locale. moment.defineLocale(localeName, config) should only be used for creating a new locale See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/define-locale/ for more info.
(node:1022) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
    at /home/debian/app/server.js:987:21
    at /home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:684:9
    at /home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:226:23
    at connectCallback (/home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:366:5)
    at /home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:599:14
    at Object.connectHandler [as callback] (/home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:285:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/debian/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:443:25)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Everything works fine on local. Every page works great online and suddenly everything crash and start reboot in loop ?

Answer (score 1):

If that is an environmental variable not seen by your server application, try restart by refreshing with the following

```
pm2 restart server --update-env
```